# Enable debug logging through OSLog

Tags: ios, oslog

I've set up logging through OSLog in my iOS App, and I've added a button to export logs with OSLogStore:

```
extension OSLog {
    private static let subsystem = Bundle.main.bundleIdentifier!
   
    @available(iOS 15.0, *)
    static func getLogs(inLast: TimeInterval) -> [OSLogEntryLog]? {
        guard let store = try? OSLogStore(scope: .currentProcessIdentifier) else { return nil }
        let startTime = store.position(timeIntervalSinceEnd: -inLast)
        guard let entries = try? store.getEntries(at: startTime).compactMap({ $0 as? OSLogEntryLog }).filter({ $0.subsystem == subsystem }) else { return nil }
        return entries
    }
}
```

This works fine when testing locally, all logs are exported even in release builds. However, when our team is testing builds through TestFlight, debug logs are not exported. Is there a way to export all logs including debug logs?

Comment: I also have this problem. In fact, I have two problems. One is that all devices don't get debug level logs, only info and higher.  The other is that some devices don't get any log entries at all.

Comment: @PaulReeder Debug-level logs are not getting stored in persistent storage. Check table given by Apple ref: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/os/logging/generating_log_messages_from_your_code

Comment: @Nick did you solve your issue?

Answer (score 4):

You need to add this to your `Info.plist`

```
<key>OSLogPreferences</key>
<dict>
    <key>your.subsystem.key.here</key>
    <dict>
        <key>your-category-here</key>
        <dict>
            <key>Level</key>
            <dict>
                <key>Enable</key>
                <string>Debug</string>
                <key>Persist</key>
                <string>Debug</string>
            </dict>
        </dict>
    </dict>
</dict>
```

Also, you might want to add

```
<key>Enable-Private-Data</key>
<true/>
```

to the same dictionary to not have all your parameters redacted.

And finally, don't use `.filter` on the `getEntries()` result, it's extremely slow. Instead use the `matching` overload with a `NSPredicate`, e.g.

```
try? store
    .getEntries(
        at: startTime, 
        matching: NSPredicate(format: "subsystem == \"\(subsystem)\"")
    )
    .compactMap({ $0 as? OSLogEntryLog })
```

Comment: I am wondering if there is any way to control logging with provisioning profile for the app in a way apple does it for some of their services. What I want to achieve is enable  logging in the released version only if provisioning profile is installed. (e.g Apple does similar thing for services like Apple Pay)

Comment: Full documentation for this can be found here: https://keith.github.io/xcode-man-pages/os_log.5.html

Answer (score -1):

Claus Jørgensen's answer works. One can indeed add the settings to an Info.plist and the debug level messages appear in OSLogStore on iOS. From reading Apple's documentation, I was assuming that the configuration of these things is only possible in macOS.

In case it helps anybody: Some information about the Info.plist is in `man 5 os_log`:

> Application-specific profiles are in an application's Info.plist file, in an OSLogPreferences dictionary.  Keys in this dictionary correspond to subsystem names, and its values are subsystem dictionaries.

I suspect, that debug level messages are not accessible from the OSLogStore - at least currently with iOS 17 / Xcode 15. From Apple's documentation ([Generating Log Messages from Your Code][1]):

> Normally, the system stores debug and info messages only in memory, ...

and:

> The severity of the log level impacts the speed at which the system logs the information. Debug logs have very low overhead because the system stores them only in memory.

From what one can see when playing with OSLogStore on iOS, it looks like OSLogStore just does not include debug messages.