# getting OSLog Logger statements on device for archived build

Tags: ios, swift, logging, oslog

Is it possible to get OSLog statements on device for a release build? If I launch the app in the simulator or on device from Xcode, the app can read and display its own log statements using the code below. But in an archived build installed on the device, nothing appears. What am I doing wrong? Or is this some sort of privacy limitation by Apple? In other StackOverflow questions, I see people asking how to turn *off* OSLog logging for release builds, so it sounds like this logs are not automatically omitted for those builds and should be available to me.

```
    public static func getLogEntries(secondsAgo: TimeInterval? = nil) throws -> [OSLogEntryLog] {
        
        let subsystem = Bundle.main.bundleIdentifier
        
        // Open the log store.
        let logStore = try OSLogStore(scope: .currentProcessIdentifier)
        
        // Get all the logs from the last so many seconds.
        let seconds: TimeInterval = (secondsAgo ?? -600) * -1
        let minutesAgo = logStore.position(date: Date().addingTimeInterval(seconds))
        
        // Fetch log objects.
        let allEntries = try logStore.getEntries(at: minutesAgo)
        
        // Filter the log to be relevant for our specific subsystem
        // and remove other elements (signposts, etc).
        return allEntries
            .compactMap { $0 as? OSLogEntryLog }
            .filter { $0.subsystem == subsystem }
    }
```

Comment: Use the Mac's Console app

Comment: The code you posted will also work on a release build. However, without `Info.plist` changes, the debug logs will be skipped, and any arguments you pass to a logline will be redacted. This answer here might be of interest to you: https://stackoverflow.com/a/77293493/95309

Comment: Thank you, @ClausJørgensen, but the code I posted above does *not* work on a release build; the method only successfully gathers log statements on debug builds run from Xcode. Do you have any idea what I am doing wrong? I am trying to build a debug screen in the app that allows viewing of log statements.

Comment: Is your bundle identifier different in your release build? We use basically the same code and it works fine on release builds (TestFlight)

Comment: I read more closely your answer again on the other question and realized that the reason this was not working was because I was using log level debug in my tests. Thanks for your help; if you want to post an explicit answer, I can mark it as accepted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Per discussion in the comments, if you want debug level logs you need to add this to your `Info.plist`

```
<key>OSLogPreferences</key>
<dict>
    <key>your.subsystem.key.here</key>
    <dict>
        <key>your-category-here</key>
        <dict>
            <key>Level</key>
            <dict>
                <key>Enable</key>
                <string>Debug</string>
                <key>Persist</key>
                <string>Debug</string>
            </dict>
        </dict>
    </dict>
</dict>
```

Answer (score 0):

> "so it sounds like this logs are not automatically omitted for those builds"

Correct. They do exist and are logged to the central logging facility. You can access them using the Console app on Mac.

> and should be available to me.

No. The app cannot access the central logging facility (OSLogStore) on iOS. Hopefully some day this will be allowed, but it currently is not, and Apple has made no particular hint that they will change this in the future. Your only option is to open a Feedback to Apple (which they will file or ignore; there is no way to know), and hope it will be added some day. If you need production logs, you will need to manage them yourself outside of OSLog.

Comment: The app can access the `OSLogStore` for the current process on iOS (since iOS 15), but maybe you meant something else here?

Comment: @ClausJørgensen This probably is a misunderstanding of mine. I may have misunderstood the docs and missed something I wish I were using. Can you post an answer explaining how to do it?

Comment: The code OP posted works fine. The caveats are that it won't include debug logs by default, and private loglines will be redacted (also by default). Which both can be solved by overriding the defaults in `Info.plist` (see https://stackoverflow.com/a/77293493/95309)